# Change /etc/hosts

Tags: linux, bash, centos, networking, curl

I want this file from `api.example.com/test/info.php` to be taken from `localhost/test/info.php`.

The idea is that I don't want all files from `api.example.com` to be taken from localhost, just the `info.php` file.

So I've tried to do that by editing `/etc/hosts` but it does not work:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
127.0.0.1   api.example.com/test/info.php
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

And I know that it does not respect the structure inside `/etc/hosts` but I'm not sure how to address that. So what can I do?

Comment: Changing `/etc/hosts` does not sound like the correct thing to do.  You say, "I want this file from `api.example.com/test/info.php` to be taken from `localhost/test/info.php`," but you don't mention what you are doing.  Are you surfing the web with a browser, providing or accessing a REST service, or doing something completely different?

Comment: @they Basically **info.php** is on another server and contains two variables. I would like those variables to be taken from my server. In info.php there is a variable that shows the date and time for the US and not for France.

Comment: When you access `info.php` via a web server running on the remote machine, you want it to have values taken from your local computer?

Comment: @roaima yes, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: So you want an arbitrary web server somewhere "out there" to have access to files on your computer? Seems a little strange to me. Most of the world is trying to ensure that other systems _cannot_ have access to their local machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hosts file will not solve this. The hosts file is for providing domain name resolution.

Assuming both localhost and example.com are web servers. A more suitable solution for this is to use a proxy so that a specific path acts as a proxy to an external server. For example with Apache on serverA (example.com) you would write in the config to request files from serverB (i.e. the remote name for localhost):

```
ProxyPass        /test/info.php  http://serverB/test/info.php 
ProxyPassReverse /test/info.php  http://serverB/test/info.php
```

This would mean that any access to /test/info.php on serverA would pull the file from serverB.

Comment: ProxyPass resolves URLs in the context of the server, so you'll end up with a loop of redirections here. Perhaps you meant Redirect

Comment: Correct, response is probably slightly misleading as the OP uses example.com and localhost. I'ved updated the response to user serverA and serverB to be clearer that there should be two separate servers.